# How to get code coverage in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, xcode6, xcode6gm

My tests are XCTests and I'm using Objective-C instead of Swift.

I've seen some articles that tackle the topic, but the seem focused on older versions of Xcode, for example:

- [Visualizing Code Coverage with Xcode](http://blog.nwoolls.com/2013/02/08/visualizing-code-coverage-with-xcode/)
- [Code Coverage Fixed for Xcode 5.1](http://qualitycoding.org/xcode51-code-coverage/)

What would be the recommended approach to get code coverage on Xcode 6? Does Apple have something built in for code coverage, maybe via Xcode CI via OSX Server?

Comment: Find an answer to this? I'm also interested.

Comment: Unfortunately no answer so far.

Comment: Have you tried to configure XCode with gcov? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1514/_index.html

Comment: It would be nice to have a minimal example of this using Travis and Coveralls.

Comment: So is it just not possible with Xcode 6? I attempted to implement that outlined in your second link and no coverage files were created..

Comment: I've managed to get Xcode coverage to work with Xcode 6. Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1514/_index.html)

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [frankencover.it](https://github.com/appsquickly/frankencover.it)

- Simple script that can be run from dev's cmd-line or CI build server.
- Produces console output as well as a detailed report in HTML format. This can be viewed locally or published as an artifact by the build server.
- Optionally includes a checker that will 'fail' the build if required coverage is not met. (Feedback only. This is a prompt to review coverage and look for useful tests that can be added ***or*** reduce the required amount. Either option may be correct. )
- Free for both commercial and open-source projects.  No hosting, sponsorship or subscription required.

**Usage:**

FTW, it has an easy-to-remember dogue-speak-esque command line interface:

```
groovy http://appsquickly.github.io/frankencover.it/with --source-dir MyProject/Source
```

**Terminal Output:**

[image]

**HTML Report:**

[image]

Comment: This makes things so much easier.

Comment: Hi @Jasper the html file seems to be missing. The coverage folder is empty. Have u come across this situation before?

Comment: @Siddarthan No. Do you have latest lcov? Please raise a Github issue

Comment: lcov: LCOV version 1.11 I guess this is the latest lcov. I shall raise a GitHub issue

Comment: Yup that version is all good. Does your project output coverage to custom folder (not DerivedData?). Frankencover has a cmdline arg to config that. Ok shall wait for gh issue.

Comment: That can be a reason too. Let me try that. Where can I lookup for the cmd line to config? I couldn't find it in  frankencover.it

Comment: I'm trying to get this working with our project as well.  We build it with CMake (using clang) but it also builds with xcode (from a project file built from the CMake project).  However, when I the test program, I'm not sure what files I should be looking for in our build/test area; I'm not even sure if the code is really instrumented.

Comment: @SteveBroberg you'll  know the code is instrumented if you can find *.gcda files after running tests (or the app). By default these go to DerivedData dir, though I'm not sure if cmake overrides this.

Answer (score 1):

We use Xcoverage for this..Check on link below, if this helps..

[Xcoverage](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/xcode-coverage/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an update, From Xcode 6 Apple having in-build code coverage tool, But Have a look at coverStory it is easy to configure test locally before push.
And providing a line by line coverage.